# iOS Push notification coming but code not called

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

In my project I have both the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method as well as the UNUserNotificationCenter `didReceive` and `willPresent` methods. In a certain edge case I observed the push notification coming to the device but no methods were called. I suspect that the edge case is intermittent network connectivity. Is my assumption correct? How should I go about handling this?

Here is the body of the push itself:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "content-available": 1,
        "alert": "...",
        "badge": "1",
        "sound": "mailsent.wav"
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let type = ... {
        switch type {
        case "...":
            self.handle(userinfo: userInfo, completion: { (value) -> (Void) in
                if (value == true) {
                    completionHandler(.newData)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(.failed)
                }
            })
            break
        default:
            completionHandler(.newData)
            break
        }
    } else {
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }
}
```

And here are the `didReceive` and `willPresent` methods:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
    ...
    completionHandler()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
    ...
    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please update your question with the notification payload that is being sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Ok, the thing is that it wont be called unless that the app is active when you receive the notification or the user taps on it, try sending the notification when the app is running so you can check it properly.

Comment: The app was in the foreground when I tried to do this. However, none of the code was called.